# Is this a safe solution to cross site form injection?

Tags: php, forms, security

Imagine we have a form like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = rand(0, 6000000);
echo '
<form method="post" action="submit.php/?token='.$_SESSION['token'].'">
...
</form>
';
?>
```

And the form handler submit.php

```
<?php
if($_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {
//form is valid, do stuff
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
//give the attacker boot
}
?>
```

Is there a way this form can be forged by running a form submit request to `http://somesite.com/submit.php?token=non-genuine-number`on third party website? We are not talking about tricking admin to click the link mid-through form edition on genuine site, when the `$_SESSION` data for token is generated and could be spoofed but someone without the correct session data.

Comment: 1 in 6000001 chance, I'd suppose.

Comment: @Blake How exactly? There is no way AFAIK to generate $_SESSION data from third party site for the target site, so even if they managed to figure out it is probably session based, still the condition would evaluate false, because $_SESSION['token'] on genuine site would be empty, as I said, only way I can think of is if someone tricked the admin midway through editing the form and then correct guessing/getting his session token

Answer (score 0):

From a security point of view, it would not be considered secure.

An attacker can assume (or even observe) when the user downloaded the form, and launch his attack at the right time. He also needs to hit a number that is chosen from 6000000, entropy seems to be ~22.5 bits, way too little already, but in reality it's even less because rand() is not cryptographically secure (as opposed to random_bytes() or random_int() or reading from /dev/urandom on Linux).

So while it may not be trivial to actually exploit, any security code review would find it a flaw as it's against the best practice.

**Edit:**

You could improve the solution a lot (effectively implementing the synchronizer token pattern correctly) by doing two simple things:

- use a secure prng like random_bytes()
- increase entropy a lot

If you generated the token like `bin2hex(random_bytes(16))`, it would be much better.

**Edit 2:**

One more thing for nitpicking. It would be best not to send the token in the URL, because URL parameters will get logged in all kind of places, where an attacker might grab it from. However, if it's a one time token (every page request generates a new one), that mitigates the risk somewhat. It would still be better to use a hidden form field as suggested by OWASP and others.

Comment: So you are saying, if I am not NASA, nobody will probably bother and I am on safe side of the fence? And going by my solution, is there a way I could potential improve it? Quick way would be to increase entropy with some ever bigger rand number.

Comment: I was trying to say it's probably hard to exploit, but I'm not that experienced at exploiting such things. I think if I had a better understanding of how exactly rand() works in PHP, it could even be very easy (or not, I don't know how good a prng that is).

I will edit my answer to suggest some easy fixes that would in fact make this much more secure.

Comment: I also think since the attacker would have to make from few thousand up to 6000000 request to that form at the correct window of opportunity to brute-force it, the chances are red flags would go up on server pretty quickly, since those are a lot of requests and in no way normal.

Comment: Probably, but why would you base your application's security on operational constraints, especially when you can so easily secure it properly?